# Querydsl @QueryInit(*.*) not working in jdk 11

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

The first two levels are triggered correctly (speed Violation.fact 1.car.vrp(NullPointerException, vrp is null)), but then Nullpointerexception.

I dont understand why.

code:

```
@Document(collection = "speed_violation")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class SpeedViolation {
...
 @NotNull
    @QueryEmbedded
    @QueryInit("*.*")
    protected Fact fact1;
...
```

class Fact:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Fact {
...
 @QueryEmbedded
    private Car car;
...
}
```

class Car:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Car {

   
    @QueryEmbedded
    private Vrp vrp;
}
```

class Vrp:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "number")
@Builder
public class Vrp {

 
    @NotNull
    private String number;
}
```

i try use in method:

```
 @Override
    public Optional<SpeedViolation> findPendingForFactViolation(String vrp,
                                                             Long complexId,
                                                             Long camera2Id,
                                                             LocalDateTime secondFactPhotoDate,
                                                             LocalDateTime maxFirstFactPhotoDate,
                                                             LocalDateTime minFirstFactPhotoDate) {
        QSpeedViolation speedViolation = QSpeedViolation.speedViolation;

        Predicate predicate = speedViolation.fact1.car.vrp`(NullPointerException)`.number.eq(vrp)
...
}
```

This happened when I switched from java 8 to java 11. If set jdk 8 all work fine.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <!-- Build properties -->
        <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <shedlock.version>3.0.0</shedlock.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
        <minio.version>7.0.2</minio.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx512m</argLine>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
        <profile.swagger />
        <profile.tls />

        <!-- Dependency versions -->
        <jhipster-dependencies.version>3.0.3</jhipster-dependencies.version>
        <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <pact.version>3.6.13</pact.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.2.2</querydsl.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
        <image-utils.version>2.1.0</image-utils.version>
        <apache-commons-text.version>1.9</apache-commons-text.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.16.0</testcontainers.version>
        <mongock.version>3.3.2</mongock.version>

        <!-- Plugin versions -->
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-idea-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-idea-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <git-commit-id-plugin.version>2.2.6</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
        <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>
        <jsr305.version>3.0.2</jsr305.version>
        <influxdb-client.version>2.14</influxdb-client.version>
        <junit.utReportFolder>${project.testresult.directory}/test</junit.utReportFolder>
        <junit.itReportFolder>${project.testresult.directory}/integrationTest</junit.itReportFolder>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <mongodb-driver.version>3.10.0</mongodb-driver.version>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-property -->
    </properties>
...
<dependencies>
        <!-- Транзакции -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>
                                org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                            </processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
                            </path>
                            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-annotation-processor -->
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Querydsl 4.x doesn't support Java 11. For Java 11, upgrade to Querydsl 5.

Comment: i try this, it dont work the same